# After updating Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 I can't open Spotify?

Tags: spotify

I have updated Ubuntu to the last version (15.04), but now I am not able to open Spotify. When I ran `spotify` in a terminal, I found that a library (`libgcrypt.so.11`) was missed.

Comment: open it in terminal, just type spotify and press enter. Then you will see the error, paste it in your main post.

Comment: Yes I  have done exactly what you suggested.  I found that a  library  (libgcrypt.so.11) was missed.

Comment: Good. Have fun with linux.  You can install the library by checking out its name and in terminal, type,  sudo apt-get libraryname

Comment: you can also search for the library name by dpkg --search libgcrypt.so.11

Comment: I found that library here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/libgcrypt11/download

Comment: If you want, but I have posted an answer too, can you mark my answer as useful?

Comment: Try reinstalling. Use sudo apt-get install --reinstall spotify. I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
[Spotify](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-app-and-Ubuntu-15-04/td-p/1121810)
It turns  out that  I had to install the library **libgcrypt.so.11**, which is located in the package `libgcrypt11`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11
```

Comment: Installing old security libraries (libgcrypt.so.11) is not recommended. This version runs fine with Ubuntu 15-10: http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/